# Python ->MySQL : UPDATE SET is not updating properly

Tags: python, mysql, sql, loops

Hi iam new to sql and i am searching for a way that lets me loop a table so if i can check if ItemName is already in a second table saved.
Thats my code
myresult and myresult2 is a fetchall() statement that SELECT FROM ItemName where samevalue is null and needs to be updated.

```
bollean_nodata = False
query = "SELECT nameItem FROM MARCT WHERE samevalue is null;"
mycursor.execute(query)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

try: 
    query = "SELECT nameItem FROM ExistingItems;"
    mycursor.execute(query)
    myresult2 = mycursor.fetchall()
except:
    bollean_nodata = True
    print("myresult2 not found making new exisitingItem data")
```

That Part is not working

```
if bollean_nodata != True:   
for i in myresult2:
        for i2 in myresult:
            if i == i2:
                query = "SELECT id FROM existingitems WHERE nameItem = %s;"
                data = str(i2[0],)
                data = (data,)
                mycursor.execute(query, data)
                id = mycursor.fetchall()
                query = "UPDATE MARCT SET samevalue = %s WHERE nameItem = %s;"
                i2 = str(i2[0])
                id = str(id[0])
                #Format the id from a string to a int
                real_id = ""
                for char in id:
                    if char == '(' or char == ')' or char == ',':
                        continue
                    else:
                        real_id += char
                real_id = int(real_id)
                data = (real_id, i2,)

                mycursor.execute(query, data)    <--- That part doesent update the table
```

That part that makes some values in it when nothings there. Not really nessesary.

```
else:
    query = "INSERT INTO EXISTINGITEMS (nameItem) VALUES (%s);"
    count = 0
    while count != len(list[0]):
        Item = str(list[0][count])
        data = (Item,)
        mycursor.execute(query, data)
        db.commit()
        count += 1
```

but the second mycursor.execute(query, data)
seems not to update the data from table one.
Can somebody say me what iam doing wrong?

Comment: If all the data is within the database, it's likely you don't need cursors to do any of this and that a single `UPDATE` could be used.  If you can provide the SQL question (with complete test case, table structure, sample data, and expected result) without the program detail, that might help.

Comment: Ah thanks. Do you got an example for this?

Comment: Sure.  But I need a little more detail about the tables (CREATE TABLE statements), just a little sample data, and the expected result, given that data.  In the MySQL command line client, `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname;` for each table will provide at least the `CREATE TABLE` detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a test case based on detail found in the question.  Hopefully, I extracted this without errors.  I assumed some of the types, based on that detail.

The test case is found here:

[Working test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ddfaf0423a8230863bb959431ac37aa9)

This assumes we are trying to transfer some string `existingitems.id` contents (while removing `(,)` characters) into `marct.samevalue` (a possible integer type), all based on rows with matching `nameItem` values, and only for `marct` rows which have `samevalue IS NULL`.

Details of the `UPDATE` are here:

```
UPDATE marct
  JOIN existingitems AS i
    ON i.nameItem = marct.nameItem
   SET marct.samevalue = REGEXP_REPLACE(i.id, '[(,)]', '')
 WHERE marct.samevalue IS NULL
;
```

Initial data `marct`:

```
+----------+-----------+
| nameItem | samevalue |
+----------+-----------+
| item1    |      NULL |
| item2    |       123 |
| item3    |      NULL |
| item4    |      NULL |
+----------+-----------+
```

Initial data `existingitems`:

```
+----------+---------+
| nameItem | id      |
+----------+---------+
| item1    | (222,5) |
| item2    | (999)   |
| item3    | 111     |
| item5    | (555)   |
+----------+---------+
```

Final `marct` contents:

```
+----------+-----------+
| nameItem | samevalue |
+----------+-----------+
| item1    |      2225 |
| item2    |       123 |
| item3    |       111 |
| item4    |      NULL |
+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks man, i aprichiate your help a loot, It works fine now jej. Its shows me i have a lot to learn in sql, doesnt got the syntax fully in my head jet. :)

Comment: @Berthold You're welcome.  If the answer is acceptable, you can `Accept` with a checkmark near the up/down vote control.